# Django render template from model variables

Tags: python, django, templates

I have a model:

```
class DocumentoPaziente(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=50)
    cognome = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=50)
    contenuto = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100000)
```

Variale content:

```
Il Paziente <font color="#000000"><font face="Arial, serif"><font size="3" style="font-size: 12pt"><span lang="zxx"><b>{{ member.cognome }}
{{ member.nome }}</b></span></font><font color="#000000"><font face="Arial, serif"><font size="3" style="font-size: 12pt"><span lang="zxx">
abitante [...]
```

In template:

```
{% autoescape off %}
{{ member.contenuto }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

It render

```
Il Paziente {{ member.cognome }} {{ member.nome }} abitante [...]
```

Expected:

```
Il Paziente Smith John abitante [...]
```

Comment: How do you call the rendering procedure here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function in your model to do the rendering properly, like:

```
from django.template import Template, Context

class DocumentoPaziente(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=50)
    cognome = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=50)
    contenuto = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100000)

    def render_content(self):
        return Template(self.contuento).render(Context({'member': self}))
```

In your template, you can then render this with:

```
{% autoescape off %}
{{ member.render_content }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: With your method it ignore variables. Now render: "Il Paziente abitante"

Comment: @JuConte: there was initially a typo, it should be `{'member': self}`, not `{'member': self}`. But it is possible (or at least not without introducing extra template tags), to rerender the output of a rendering. That would be bad software design I think.

Comment: ```
    def render_content(self):
        return Template(self.contenuto).render(Context({'member': self}))
    def render_name(self):
        return Template(self.nome).render(Context({'member': self}))
``` It work, one def every variable TY