# Custom render method in django model that is callable from the template

Tags: django, django-templates

I would like my django model to offer a render method that could be called from django template.

I have tried to achieve this with template nodes with following code.

```py
# models.py
class PaymentNode(template.Node):
  def __init__(self, title):
    self.title = title

  def render(self, context):
    return 'payment of ' + context['saldo'] + '€: ' + self.title # Here we could render a template etc. 

class BankPayment(models.Model):
  title = 'Bank Payment'
  
  def render_payment(self):
    return PaymentNode(self.title)
```

Then, in the views.py I could inject different payment models and the saldo, that is used in the payment type rendering, into the context

```py
# views.py
class MyView(TemplateView):
  def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ctx = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    ctx['payments'] = [ BankPayment() ]
    ctx['saldo'] = 10
    return ctx
```

In the template I would like to render all payments like this:

```
Pay {{ saldo }} using one of these:
<ul>
{% for p in payments %}
  <li>{{ p.render_payment }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This should have outcome of `payment of 10€: Bank Payment`. But django template does not render the Node, it just outputs `<models.PaymentNode object at 0x7ffb52054668>`

Is it possible to do this? It doesn't have to be `template.Node` but I would like to access the context in the rendering logic. The amount and type of payment types will differ. Is a custom templatetag my only option?

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56716875/216846) is close but does not take context in.

Comment: The current approach couple the model and the template, which isn't usually recommended. I suggest an alternative approach: define an [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags), and then you could do `{% for p in payments %}{% payment p %}{% endfor %}`

Comment: Note that `[ BankPayment() ]` is a list which contains a single payment with no values set. If you want to fetch all of the payments from the database, you would do `ctx['payments'] = BankPayment.objects.all()`